# drupal7 get content with manual sql

Tags: mysql, database, join, drupal-7, inner-join

Im trying to get all the `articles` from the drupal7 table using manual sql method, I am trying to use the tables named `field_data_body`, `node`, `file_usage`, `file_managed`. What I really want is something like this:

```
body_value | body_summary | nid | title | created_time | uri
```

I used the following `sql` code:

```
SELECT distinct body.body_value, body.body_summary, node.nid, node.title, FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created) as created, file_managed.uri
            FROM 
                node 
                    INNER JOIN field_data_body as body ON node.nid = body.entity_id
                    INNER JOIN file_managed ON file_usage.fid = file_managed.fid
            WHERE body.entity_id = node.nid
                AND node.type = 'article'
                AND node.status = '1'
            GROUP BY node.nid
            ORDER BY node.nid desc
```

it worked but I got only those `articles` that has an `image` with it and all the rest got `ignored`. Can someone suggest me on how to deal with these sql conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  b.body_value,
  b.body_summary,
  n.nid,
  n.title,
  n.created,
  fm.uri
FROM
node n
LEFT JOIN field_data_body AS b ON n.nid = b.entity_id
LEFT JOIN file_usage AS fu ON fu.id = n.nid
LEFT JOIN file_managed AS fm ON fm.fid = fu.fid
WHERE n.type = 'article'
  AND n.status = '1'
GROUP BY n.nid
ORDER BY n.nid DESC;
```